# Parsing a JSON string within a JSON string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm confused on how to use Javascript to parse a JSON string. I have a string that is this:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "record": {
            "ID": "2",
            "user_id": "11",
            "sub_json": "{\"ntest\":\"1234\",\"allthis\":\"stuff\",\"somethingelse\":\"whatever\"}"
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to pull the values for user_id and sub_json out. How do I do this in Javascript?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The string you posted looks like the return value from an API call. If it is, then the whole string needs to be parsed first before you can access the `user_id` and `sub_json` values:

```
const Str = '{"success":true,"data":{"record":{"ID":"2","user_id":"11","sub_json":"{\\"ntest\\":\\"1234\\",\\"allthis\\":\\"stuff\\",\\"somethingelse\\":\\"whatever\\"}"}}}';
const Obj = JSON.parse(Str);
const UserId = Obj.data["record"]["user_id"];
const SubJsonObj = JSON.parse(Obj.data["record"]["sub_json"]);
```

If the string you posted does *not* need to be parsed, then you only have to parse the `sub_json` string within it:

```
const Obj = {
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "record": {
            "ID": "2",
            "user_id": "11",
            "sub_json": "{\"ntest\":\"1234\",\"allthis\":\"stuff\",\"somethingelse\":\"whatever\"}"
        }
    }
};
const UserId = Obj.data.record.UserId;
const SubJsonObj = JSON.parse(Obj.data.record.sub_json);
```